# Why did Paxton create the hybrid baby?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

In the final episodes of Enterprise, we discover

> that John Paxton used DNA from Tucker and T'Pol to create a half-human half-Vulcan baby.

It is unclear to me from the episodes why he actually did this. Is a clear explanation ever given?

He does reveal

> the baby

to the world in his big speech; showing how it is a threat to the future of humanity. But did he create

> the child

simply to have a prop to use during that speech? That definitely doesn’t seem like a necessary part of his plan. Was he simply attempting to learn

> whether or not human and Vulcan DNA is compatible, to know if he had to fear the possible end of humanity through cross-breeding

?

Again, he had his reasons to fear contact with other alien species even if that had proved impossible.

Comment: To demonstrate that humans and vulcans can breed and that it was happening.

Comment: To make the human population think that their unique culture, and genetic were going away and were blending in with Vulcans and other extraterrestrials, I believe he said something about humans becoming just a footnote in a medical journal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are pretty much answering your own question, seeing he only created the baby as proof that mixing between different species is possible, suggesting that it is eventually possible that there won't be a "pure" human left in the distance future.

This is an allegory for an issue that became prominent in the late 1800's (and is still referred to today) that by allowing "race-mixing" certain races would eventually disappear in to extinction.

And just as they used this in real life as an "argument" in favor of segregation,  Paxton uses this as a political point to further his anti-alien rhetoric's.

It's a common trope in SC-fi and fantasy works based on real life "racist" rhetoric's. (Like in Dragon Age where the child of an Human/Elven couple is always human, therefor elves who have relationships with humans are sometimes shunned by their community because they view their actions as helping the extinction of Elven kind.)